# Essential "code toolset" for java/.Net

Tags: java, .net, libraries

What essential code packages do you use on every project, that's not included in the BCL or java distribution?

- Mocking/Stubbing
- Unit Tests
- IOC / Dependency Injection
- Logging
- ORM
- ...

Which implementation of the above do you use?

What essentials did I miss?

Comment: Do you mean categories of tools, or what actual flavour of tool? The question seems a bit broad...

Comment: This is starting to look a lot like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662956/most-useful-free-net-libraries ... at the very least it should be a community wiki.

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130095/most-useful-free-java-libraries for the java portion of the question....

Comment: Accepted, thanks for the references.

Answer (score 4):

This is my list for Java:

1. Spring for dependency injection,
   AOP, handling of configuration and glueing systems together
2. Easymock for mocking.
3. JUnit for testing Log4j for logging.
4. Hibernate for ORM.
5. CXF for web-services.
6. Apache Commons in particular:

   - Codec for encoding/decoding (ex Base64)
   - Lang for various convenience classes
   - IO for enhanced file handling.
7. Google Collections for their
   generics-enabled Collection
   functions.
8. JIBX for pretty good XML
   marshalling/unmarshalling
9. EhCache for general caching
10. Not really a java package, but all my projects use Maven for dependency management and build automation.
11. uncommon-maths for any statistics and random number generation required.

Answer (score 0):

- [.NET Reflector (Red Gate)](http://reflector.red-gate.com/download.aspx) (reflection, obviously)
- [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) (logging)
- [Nunit](http://nunit.org) (Unit Testing)
- [Rhino Mocks](http://ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks.aspx) (Mocking)
- [NHibernate](http://nhibernate.org) (or more recently Linq-to-SQL) (ORM)

Answer (score 0):

- Moq (Mocking)
- NUnit (Unit Testing)
- Ninject (Dependency Injection)
- NHibernate with Fluent NHibernate (OR/M)
- Sonic.NET Migrations (Migrations)
- FinalBuilder (Continuous Integration)
- YUI Test (JavaScript Unit Testing)
- WatiN (Enable Continuous Integration of JavaScript Unit Tests)
- WatiN (Integration Tests)

Answer (score 0):

- Visual Studio - IDE
- Resharper - IDE Enhancements
- Visual SVN - IDE Enhancements
- [RockScroll](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingRockScroll.aspx) - IDE Enhancements
- SVN - Source control
- .Net Reflector - Tools
- NHibernate - ORM
- Moq - Mock
- NUnit - Test
- Castle Windsor - IOC
- TeamCity - Continuous Integration